# error in passing data through navigation in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-functional-component

I'm new to react native world and I'm trying to integrate a calendar with a time slot picker, so I'm trying to pass the selected date from the calendar to the slot picker page but I'm having this Error when I press on a date in the calendar and I couldn't fix it.
**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')**

This is my calendar function:

```
const RequestMeeting = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ margin: 100, }}>
      <Button title="Show modal" onPress={toggleModal} />

      <Modal isVisible={isModalVisible} avoidKeyboard={true} scrollHorizontal={true} propagateSwipe={true}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={{ margin: 50, backgroundColor: 'gray', borderRadius: 20, padding: 20, margin: 20 }}>
        
            <Text style={styles.heading}>Request to Buy/Rent</Text>

            <View style={{ paddingBottom: 10 }}></View>

            <View >
              <Calendar
                onDayPress={(day) => navigation.navigate("Slot", { bookingDate: day })}
                style={styles.calendar}
                hideExtraDays
                theme={{
                  selectedDayBackgroundColor: 'green',
                  todayTextColor: 'green',
                  arrowColor: 'green',
                }}
              />
            </View>

            <Button
              buttonStyle={styles.register}
              title="Send Buy/Rent request" 
              />
            <Button
             buttonStyle={styles.cancelbtn} 
             title="Cancel" 
             onPress={toggleModal} 
             />

          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};
```

And this is my time slot picker function:

```
const jsonData = {
    "slots": {
        "slot1": "9:00am to 9:30am",
        "slot2": "9:30am to 10:00am",
        "slot3": "10:00am to 10:30am",
        "slot4": "10:30am to 11:00am",
        "slot5": "11:00am to 11:30am",
        "slot6": "11:30am to 12:00pm"
    }
}

const Slot = ({ navigation }) => {
    const onPressBack = () => {
        const { goBack } = navigation
        goBack()
    }
    const slots = jsonData.slots
    const slotsarr = Object.keys(slots).map(function (k) {
        return (
            <View key={k} style={{ margin: 5 }}>

                <TouchableOpacity >
                    <Text>{slots[k]}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>)
    });
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
            <View >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressBack()}><Text >Back</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                <Text ></Text>
                <Text ></Text>
            </View>
            { slotsarr}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that wherever you are rendering `RequestMeeting` or `Slot` (whichever one has the error) it's not getting the `navigation` prop.  If it is rendered as a `Screen` then it will get the prop from the `Navigator`.  If it's not a top-level screen then you need to pass down the prop from a parent or access it with the `useNavigation` hook.

Docs: [Access the navigation prop from any component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop)